# Debugging Segmentation errors with Valgrind and C++/SFML

Tags: c++, valgrind, sfml

I am developing a video game with c ++ and SFML in Ubuntu. When executing my program, the execution of my program stops with the error "Segmentation fault".

Looking for solutions on the Internet, I found **Valgrind**, a tool that provides information about errors related to memory misuse, etc.

When executing it, it provides me with the following information, **but I do not know how to interpret it correctly to find the error:**

```
=22886== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22886== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22886== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22886== Command: ./galaga
==22886== 
Child local position: (100.000000;500.000000)
==22886== Invalid read of size 8
==22886==    at 0x4014E8: Entity::GetPosition(Entity::SPACE) (Entity.cpp:44)
==22886==    by 0x4016A8: Entity::SetParent(Entity*) (Entity.cpp:92)
==22886==    by 0x401B43: Game::Game() (Game.cpp:25)
==22886==    by 0x40252C: main (main.cpp:5)
==22886==  Address 0x18 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==22886== 
==22886== 
==22886== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==22886==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x18
==22886==    at 0x4014E8: Entity::GetPosition(Entity::SPACE) (Entity.cpp:44)
==22886==    by 0x4016A8: Entity::SetParent(Entity*) (Entity.cpp:92)
==22886==    by 0x401B43: Game::Game() (Game.cpp:25)
==22886==    by 0x40252C: main (main.cpp:5)
==22886==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==22886==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==22886==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==22886==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==22886==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==22886== 
==22886== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22886==     in use at exit: 6,761,843 bytes in 2,269 blocks
==22886==   total heap usage: 11,939 allocs, 9,670 frees, 232,826,337 bytes allocated
==22886== 
==22886== LEAK SUMMARY:
==22886==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22886==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22886==      possibly lost: 360,477 bytes in 67 blocks
==22886==    still reachable: 6,401,366 bytes in 2,202 blocks
==22886==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==22886==                         newarray           : 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==22886==                         multipleinheritance: 104 bytes in 1 blocks
==22886==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22886== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==22886== 
==22886== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22886== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: you'd rather use a debugger such as `gdb` to figure out where your program is crashing and why.

Comment: It looks like you have null pointer to entity

Comment: In this function `Entity::GetPosition(Entity::SPACE)` in this file `Entity.cpp` in line `44` you probably try to access the memory that was not allocated. Post the source code. Also, run `ulimit -c unlimited`, run your program again, wait for it to crash, and then inspect the stack trace from the core with `gdb`.

Comment: I think it's when he calls `SetParent`, the Entity passed as parameter may be null. So he should definitely check in his file Game.cpp, line 25.